# If statement create array within an array

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, multidimensional-array

How if at all possible could an if statement add an array within an array.

example.

```
array(
  array(
    'name' => 'name',
    'type' => 'type',
    'label' => 'label',
  ),
  if( $a = $x ){
     array(
       'name' => 'name',
       'type' => 'type',
       'label' => 'label',
     ),
  }
  array(
    'name' => 'name',
    'type' => 'type',
    'label' => 'label',
  ),
)
```

I receive a parse error unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting ')'

Comment: You can not do that “inside” the array syntax, you need to do these two things separately.

Comment: You should start with the basic of PHP

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This will Works.

```
$a = 1;
$x = 1;
$array = [];
$array[] = array(
    'name' => 'name',
    'type' => 'type',
    'label' => 'label',
);
if( $a == $x ){
  $array[] =  array(
      'name' => 'name',
      'type' => 'type',
      'label' => 'label',
  );
}
$array[] =  array(
  'name' => 'name',
  'type' => 'type',
  'label' => 'label',
);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => name
            [type] => type
            [label] => label
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => name
            [type] => type
            [label] => label
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => name
            [type] => type
            [label] => label
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope help:

```
$a = 1;
$x = 1;

$array = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'name',
        'type' => 'type',
        'label' => 'label',
    ),

    array(
      'name' => 'name',
      'type' => 'type',
      'label' => 'label',
    ),
);

if ( $a === $x ) {

    $array[] = array(
        'name' => 'name',
        'type' => 'type',
        'label' => 'label',
    );
}

print_r($array);
```